# How to exclude an app from Force Dark Mode?

Tags: android-10, dark-mode

So Basically I want to exclude only one app (Ratio launcher if it matters) and found no apparent way to do it easily. Closest I got while searching, I came across [DarQ](https://labs.xda-developers.com/store/app/com.kieronquinn.app.darq). It allows to apply dark mode to specific apps. But the problems with this are as:

1. I do not want to include app as there are 250+ apps on my phone
   (don't ask me what do I do with them cause even I don't know ha!) so
   just ticking all of them does not seem feasible as I want it all
   over the place and not on specific app only. There is no way to
   backup app list as well so not just a one time hussle.
2. It needs to plug in my phone to PC and run their script everytime I
   restart my phone.
3. Even when I do not restart my phone but leave it alone for a while
   on battery saver mode and open an app, dark mode is gone again. Open
   DarQ only to find out it needs me to run that script again.
4. Installing a new app does not add it to the list automatically so I
   have to start all over everytime I install a new app or uninstall
   and reinstall an existing app.

So obviously far from ideal. But even if it did work flawlessly, it would be a more feasible solution for me to have exclude dark mode functionality then include dark mode one. Would be so much better if it were just builtin to the system's Force Dark mode.

P.S. My phone isn't rooted. Any suggestion which might better situation even a bit might be good as well.

Comment: I don't think it's possible in any straightforward manner. All apps which set [`MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatDelegate.html#MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM) are turned to dark theme when OS switches. All other apps which set e.g. `MODE_NIGHT_YES` or `MODE_NIGHT_NO` aren't affected. So it depends on the app developers.